# Can't use function already defined

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a new Python coder and when I trying to do a code with definitions it always gives me an error about name is not defined.

The error is:
average = compute_average_of_series(oc_raw)
NameError: name 'compute_average_of_series' is not defined

```
def compute_average_of_series(self,data_series):
    avg=sum(data_series)/len(data_series)
    return avg

average = compute_average_of_series(oc_raw)
```

The oc_raw is a list of data exact from a table.

```
oc_raw = self.data_l[self.fields_list_IN.index('Oil - consumption(bbl/day)')]
```

I think I have defined the compute_average_of_series, why it says not defined?

Comment: The first argument is `self`, is this function a method on a class?

Comment: Does calling it as `self.compute_average_of_series(oc_raw)` work?

Comment: Change it to self.compute_average_of_series(or_raw) work! Thank you so much, Stuti!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not defining a class method you shouldn't have the `self`. You get the `NameError` because python can't find a method called `compute_average_of_series` using only one argument. Delete the `self` from the method arguments and try running.

If you were trying to define a class method then you are calling the method the wrong way, since the method should be called from an object of that class.